# DefaultValue for System.Drawing.SystemColors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have a line color property in my custom grid control. I want it to default to `Drawing.SystemColors.InactiveBorder`. I tried:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(System.Drawing.SystemColors), "InactiveBorder")]
public Color LineColor { get; set; }
```

But it doesn't seem to work. How do I do that with the default value attribute?

Answer (score 13):

You need to change first argument from `SystemColors` to `Color`.
It seems that there is no type converter for the `SystemColors` type, only for the `Color` type.

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color),"InactiveBorder")]
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the link Matt posted, the DefaultValue attribute doesn't set the default value of the property, it just lets the form designer know that the property *has* a default value. If you change a property from the default value it is shown as bold in the properties window.

You can't set a default value using automatic properties - you'll have to do it the old-fashioned way:

```
class MyClass
{
    Color lineColor = SystemColors.InactiveBorder;

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public Color LineColor {
        get {
            return lineColor;
        }

        set {
            lineColor = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If one had to right click on the attribute in the property window during design time, and choose the _Reset_ command, an error will be displayed indicating that a `bool` cannot be converted to a `Color`. @aku solution will work.

Comment: In addition to showing the property bold or not, the Forms designer does not serialize the property if it has the value specified in the `DefaultValueAttribute`, i.e. no code is generated in the `InitializeComponent` method for this property in this case.